# Keycloak-Remix integration: where should I place the checks?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, remix, remix.run

I'm looking into Remix, and I would like to have authentication with Keycloak, an oauth authentication server. Most examples I find online don't use an external auth server with Remix, and the few people mentioning doing this have not provided examples.

I just have the initial notes application that comes as default with the create-remix command. I would like if possible to replace the default authentication with my external auth server, as a proof of concept. In my ideal scenario, the backend redirects the user to the Keycloak auth page, and once we receive a token, the backend shares the returned token with the front-end, as it loads the first bits of the app. This gets saved in the browser so that the user is authenticated. Then I have doubts on how the refresh token cycle and logout would work, but this is not my main concern now.

So, even if in theory it looks like Remix could perfectly implement a BFF proxy pattern (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff-pr) I still don't understand what files are the concern of the backend and the front-end, and I don't trust I can implement this architecture safely without understanding where each bit of code is being run.

What I would like is ideally to see a working example, if not, any explanation that might come closest to that

In case is helpful for context, keycloack provides a js package to facilitate doing the requiered calls, I just don't know where to place them in remix

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [remix-auth](https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-auth) and more specifically the [keycloak strategy](https://github.com/mlcsthor/remix-auth-keycloak)?

I recently extended the remix-auth-oauth2 strategy to work with [Kinde](https://kinde.com/). It seems to work really well.